# PHP To Call a SOAP Webservice

Tags: php, soap

i would like some help please.

I am trying to call a webservice using PHP and i am having problems with different kind of messages.

The WSDL is "http://195.144.16.7/ElastrakEDI/ElastrakEDI.asmx?WSDL" and the Web Service is Called GetPartMaster. The username and password at first are both TESTUID and TESTPWD ( for testing purposes ).

The XML Below is the Request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:edi="http://elastrak.gr/edi/">
   <soap:Header>
      <edi:AuthHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <edi:Username>TESTUID</edi:Username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <edi:Password>TESTPWD</edi:Password>
      </edi:AuthHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <edi:GetPartMaster/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This XML is the response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Header>
      <AuthHeader xmlns="http://elastrak.gr/edi/">
         <Username>TESTUID</Username>
         <Password>TESTPWD</Password>
      </AuthHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <GetPartMasterResponse xmlns="http://elastrak.gr/edi/">
         <GetPartMasterResult>
            <elastrakPartMasterFile xmlns="">
               <PartMasterURL>http://195.144.16.7/elastrakEDI/Temp/Parts/OTWKOJL4.txt</PartMasterURL>
               <ErrorCode/>
               <ErrorDescription/>
            </elastrakPartMasterFile>
         </GetPartMasterResult>
      </GetPartMasterResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried the php code below but still cant get it to work

```
<?php

$wsdl = 'http://195.144.16.7/ElastrakEDI/ElastrakEDI.asmx?WSDL';

$trace = true;
$exceptions = true;

$xml_array['Username'] = 'TESTUID';
$xml_array['Password'] = 'TESTPWD';

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$response = $client->GetPartMaster($xml_array);

try
{
   $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
   $response = $client->GetPartMaster($xml_array);
}

catch (Exception $e)
{
   echo "Error!";
   echo $e -> getMessage ();
   echo 'Last response: '. $client->__getLastResponse();
}

$response = $response->GetPartMaster->PartMasterURL;

var_dump($response);

?>
```

Thank you again for your time and Help.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is currently wrongly constructed as you must take into account that therse is actually thow parts in the request:

- the SOAP header, containing the username and password
- the SOAP body, containing the GetPartMaster element

Take a look to the [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.soapclient.php) class and the [__setSoapHeaders](http://php.net/manual/fr/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php) method.

This is why I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to PHP generator to send SOAP Request as it will allow you to easily construct the request and then handle the response while using the OOP approach and not wondering how to send the parameters. Using the generated PHP SDK and a good IDE such as PhpStorm or any Eclipse based IDE with autocompletion, it'll be easy to find your way. Try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.